# Why is the destructor only called once here?

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm looking through old exam problems for an upcomming exam and one of the questions went like this:

```
//How many times is Foo's destructor called when func() is called?
void func(){
    Foo a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Foo *c = new Foo();
        a = *c;
    }
}
```

And the correct answer was 1. Can anyone explain to me how it isn't called once for each new Foo created in the for-loop?

Comment: Time to read up on what `new` does.

Comment: When you allocate an object on a heap (i.e. via `new` keyword) then you have to call the destructor explicitely. The only implicit call to the destructor is when `a` goes out of scope, i.e. when `func()` exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what your code is actually doing:

```
void func(){
    Foo a; // Creates an object in the stack that will be destroyed once the function scope is no longer valid (meaning, when the function call is finished).
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Foo *c = new Foo(); // this line allocates memory for a new object and stores a pointer to that memory in 'c'
        a = *c; // Makes a field-by-field copy (to put it simple) of the memory pointed by c into the object a. No new memory is allocated, no memory is destroyed
    }
}
```

As you can see, the memory allocated by `new Foo()` was never destroyed, you need to call `delete c;` at some point to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object with `new` you need to delete it with `delete` for the destructor to be called and the memory freed. So the only object that will have it's destructor called is `a` which is created statically and destroyed when `func` ends.

Comment: Perhaps also worth mentioning, since the OP might not realise it, is that `a`  and `*c` continue to be two distinct objects, even after the assignment `a = *c;`.